# What happened to the branch v5-master?

Tags: audiokit

I have been developing using AudioKit v5-master. This morning the branch v5-master appears to be missing. I changed SPM to access v5-main. Now I get the package, but the compile of the package produces 2657 "Issues".

What do I do now?

Comment: Tried v5-develop with similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github has changed to naming the default branch main instead of master, and we followed suit. The AudioKit Cookbook uses v5-main and seems to work. This is a pretty unspecific question, like what kind of warnings or errors do you get?

Comment: AKNode is not a member type of 'AudioKit'. Same with AKInput. I thought the "AsK were all removed.

Comment: Possibly something got corrupted on your machine and now Xcode is seeing some old version of AudioKit in a cache or something. Definitely no AKNodes in v5

Comment: OK, now getting more normal results. I had deleted AudioKit from the Frameworks list on the General settings tab, thinking it was extraneous because of the SPM entry. I added this back.

Comment: I am now getting an error "Missing required modules: 'CAudioKit', 'soundpipe'

Comment: I'd remove that frameworks entry and the SPM and start with a clean SPM installation of AudioKit.

Comment: That succeeded. Thanks.